# VSCode php server [404] / - No such file or directory problem

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have installed php server on my vscode with a proper php server from php.net used at $PATH
But when I try to press

```
PHP Server: Serve project
```

I get the following error:

```
[Tue Oct 25 21:30:53 2022] PHP 8.1.11 Development Server (http://localhost:3000) started

[Tue Oct 25 21:34:55 2022] [::1]:62162 Accepted

[Tue Oct 25 21:34:55 2022] [::1]:62163 Accepted

[Tue Oct 25 19:34:55 2022] [404] / - No such file or directory 
[Tue Oct 25 21:34:55 2022] [::1]:62163 [404]: GET / - No such file or directory

[Tue Oct 25 21:34:55 2022] [::1]:62163 Closing

[Tue Oct 25 21:36:07 2022] [::1]:62162 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
[Tue Oct 25 21:36:07 2022] [::1]:62162 Closing
```